# Cannot register alias 'springSecurityFilterChain' for name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'

Tags: spring-boot

Getting this error when I start my application.

```
WrapperJarApp Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register alias 'springSecurityFilterChain' for name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Alias would override bean definition 'springSecurityFilterChain'
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.checkForAliasCircle(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1140)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.core.SimpleAliasRegistry.registerAlias(SimpleAliasRegistry.java:80)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.registerFilterChainProxyIfNecessary(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:356)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse(HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:115)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:105)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511)
WrapperJarApp Error:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
WrapperJarApp Error:    ... 35 more
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I am using spring-boot 2.6.6 and spring-framework 5.3.18.

The web.xml have

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I need the following in my application.properties file.

```
# Allow bean definition override
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: This looks like a workaround rather than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

i used this in my application but unfortunately it is not working. Was it fixed the problem for you?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is an issue with reputation and people cannot comment on answer. The only option is to propose another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message after an update of Spring Boot to 2.1++. Besides the `<http>` Spring XML security context definition, I had also used an `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation. This was necessary to work around a bug in earlier Spring versions, but it caused the modern versions to report the name conflict that you observed, too. I removed the annotation and all was well.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security gives the annotation (with a configuration class) and the `<http>` Spring XML definition as alternative ways to achieve the same target.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).